# Array built with db values behaving differently than hard coded array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

When I use values fetched from a comma-separated list in a db to form an array, I am having trouble getting them to behave the same way as hard coded arrays.

I believe this is due to the syntax within the array when it's created from db values, specifically that values aren't being encased in quotes, but I haven't successfully figured out how to insert them into the array itself.

For example, when I run the snippet which I've posted at the bottom of the page using:

**Array (hard coded):**

```
$colors_loveArray = array('Black','Charcoal','Light_Gray','White','Royal_Blue','Dodger_Blue','Red');
```

*The output is:*

> Array = 'Black','Charcoal','Light_Gray','White','Royal_Blue','Dodger_Blue','Red',
>
> Matches: Black

**Array formed with values fetched from db (comma-separated list):**

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {         
    $colors_loveArray[] = $row['colors_love'];
}
```

*The output is:*

> Array = 'Black,Charcoal,Light_Gray,White,Royal_Blue,Dodger_Blue,Red',
>
> No Match Black

---

**Code which is being run:**

```
$Color='Black';

echo "$colors_loveArray = ";
foreach ($colors_loveArray as $value) {
    echo "'".$value."',";
}

if (in_array($Color, $colors_loveArray)) {
    echo "Matches: ", $Color;
}
Else {
    echo "No Match ", $Color;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all the awesome help :-) Since I could only accept one answer, I accepted @Benpix because it was so straightforward and easy to understand, and upvoted Tengiz & showdev's answers :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `explode` your comma-delimited string.

```
explode(",", $row['colors_love']);
```

Which will give you the same as your hard-coded array.

Comment: Thank you for giving me such a perfect answer - it's not only the rare one that's super straightforward and easy to understand, it also answered my question and helped me learn something new :-D I'm now curious to know why I had to do an explode (and what it's actually doing - is it just inserting quotes or does it actually convert it into something, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, your variable $colors_loveArray contains the following:

```
array(1) "Black,Charcoal,Light_Gray,White,Royal_Blue,Dodger_Blue,Red"
```

and you might want to break is to an array using

```
$arr = explode(',', $colors_loveArray);
```

also, if your CSV file is multiline, you need to separate each line first:

```
$lines = explode("\r\n", $colors_loveArray); // could be just \r or \n or \r\n as a line separator
```

Answer (score 0):

The hard coded array is an array of 7 values that your code display as as CSV.

The DB array seems to be an array of 1 CSV value.

`"Black"` doesn't match the only value of this array, which is `"Black,Charcoal,Light_Gray,White,Royal_Blue,Dodger_Blue,Red"`.

Comment: Thank you for helping to elucidate the problem :-)